# A little bit lost with goQuery selection

Tags: go, goquery

I'm new to Go and I'm trying to learn it by making a repost bot. Anyway, I'm having a problem that I don't know how to solve exactly.

I have the following Struct:

```
type Post struct {
    Title string
    Url   string
}
```

And I'm trying to get these values using goQuery, like this:

```
var title = doc.Find(".title.title.may-blank").Each(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) {
        fmt.Println("Title:", s.Text())
})
```

But when I try to set the value to the Post struct, I get this error:

```
cannot use title (type *goQuery.Selection) as type string in field value.
```

Ok, that makes sense, but how can I cast it to string? I've tried s.Text() but it doesn't works. I thought about making a function that returns a string, but I'm not sure if this would work.

I'll appreciate if someone can help me, thanks in advance!

Comment: what about `s.Html()` ?

Comment: It works when I print it, but the error on my Post struct is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `.Each` returns the original `*goquery.Selection` so that you can chain calls.  If you need to get the string value, you just assign it directly, like this:

```
var title string
doc.Find(".title.title.may-blank").Each(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) {
    title = s.Text()
})
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I'll try that as soon as possible.